# How to specify domain name while creating jdbc resource/connection pool in glassfish 3

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish-3

I have multiple domains in a glassfish 3 server. I am able to login to different domains using glassfish admin console and I want to create jdbc resource/connection pool for a particular domain (say domain2). I know, I can create it using admin console. But I want to do it through CLI. I checked the format of `create-jdbc-connection-pool` and `create-jdbc-resource` commands. It does not take any parameter where I can specify the domain name.

Can somebody tell me how to do this using CLI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources are stored within the domain, so you implicitly define the domain when logging in. If you login to `domain2`, the resources are created in `domain2`. You can further define the `target` of the resource by using `--target` clause on each `create-blah` command. The target would be a `server` or a `cluster` within the domain you have logged in and issue the command against.

Comment: 1. Can't I execute asadmin commands directly without logging in to any domain?  2. This is the description for --target option in `create-jdbc-connection-pool` command - Do not specify this option. This option is retained for compatibility with other releases. If you specify this option, a syntax error does not occur. Instead, the subcommand runs successfully and the option is silently ignored.

Comment: 1. It depends. For example, `start domain domainName` is executed locally and does not require login to a domain. However, all remote sub-commands (like `create-jdbc-resource`) requires a domain into which the command is executed.

Comment: 2. You are right: `jdbc-connection-pool` is per domain; A `jdbc-resource` on the other hand is activated on one or more `--target`s [see this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/create-jdbc-resource-1.html)

Comment: So how to perform `create-jdbc-connection-pool` on a particular domain through `asadmin` command?

Comment: Each domain is administered via its DAS which listens to different port. Default port for domain1 is 4848. By defining the domain's port in [asadmin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1758/asadmin-1m/index.html) (`asadmin --host hostName --port portNumber`) you effectively select a domain.