# How to run an asadmin command for a specific glassfish-domain?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, asadmin

I'm trying to run a number of commands, such as:`asadmin create-custom-resource`, however, I have multiple domains, and I wish to specify which domain to be affected.

How do I run asadmin commands and specify which domain to be affected?

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't specify a domain directly for most of the `asadmin` commands.

But you can specify the **Domain Administration Server**, which controls the domain. It identifies the domain indirectly. To do this just use `--host` and `--port` parameters:

```
asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 create-custom-resource ...
```

**See also:**

- [Glassfish 3.1.1 - How to enable secure admin for different domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619063/glassfish-3-1-1-how-to-enable-secure-admin-for-different-domains)
- [How to specify domain name while creating jdbc resource/connection pool in glassfish 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189162/how-to-specify-domain-name-while-creating-jdbc-resource-connection-pool-in-glass)